# How to see vertex alpha transparency?

Tags: transparency, vertex-colors

How can I see vertex alpha as I paint it in Vertex Paint mode in 2.8? I get how to see vertex colors, via the node system, in LookDev, but I can't seem to figure how to see vertex alpha as I go to add and erase it...

Comment: I know this is old but here's the trick for anyone like me stumbling upon this in search for an answer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Km1HLQpbCoo

Answer (score 1):

It's often wise to set up your material and open up a material or rendered preview viewport.  You can have multiple viewports open.

[image]

You can paint in either window.  For alpha in a material preview, you'll need to set an appropriate alpha blend mode for your material, and to set that, you'll have to temporarily switch to the Eevee renderer-- material preview is just an Eevee render.